# Lewis Acid/Base Chemistry

Tags: acid-base

I'm looking for some clarification on Lewis Acid/Base Chemistry.  For the Acids do they have to accept a full pair of electrons to be considered a Lewis acid, or do they just have to accept an electron, and vice versa for Lewis Bases?

Comment: A Lewis acid as an electronic gap somewhere. A Lewis base as a lone pair somewhere. $\ce{AlCl3}$ is a Lewis acid with an electronic gap on the aluminum. $\ce{NH3}$ is a Lewis base with a  lone pair on the nitrogen. You'll find more details on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases)